# Unable to integrate a full blown ABAP code editor in Angular application

Tags: angular, abap

I have made an angular application that needs a code editor to show codes. I can't randomly use any code editor but an ABAP Editor or eclipse only. Cannot find any documentation on these two editors to integrate them with UI frameworks. So it's like embedding any one of two code editors in an Angular application.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm an ABAP developer. I don't understand why you want to use a SAP official ABAP editor. One is running via SAP GUI for Windows (old SAP proprietary software, not HTML), one is running via a plugin (named ADT, ABAP Developer Tools) in Eclipse. Do you really want to embed Eclipse in an angular application? Eventually, SAP GUI may be simulated in HTTP/HTML, but I think that the ABAP editor is awful. What do you want to do with this embedded ABAP editor?

Comment: use [WebGUI](https://www.skybuffer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/03.png), for instance https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2016/03/activation-of-sap-webgui/ and start it in iframe. just as a quick shot

Comment: Have a look to abapLint project as well: https://abaplint.org/ There is a VSCode extension so I guess you could do something similar to show ABAP code in your app

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your valuable input. @SandraRossi : As you asked about why it is needed, so actually it is the requirement of the application so that more SAP functionality could be achieved using that editor. 

So, basically it is like an angular application is there having a page that will have table. In that table a column name "Code" will be there in which link is there. When a user will click on that link, a new window should open with a web based ABAP Editor. It should open in browser. 

Having a hard time to find any information on this.

Comment: The official frontend ABAP editors do almost nothing by themselves. They are connected to a backend which executes the developer requests. If you just want a lint, I think RaTiO gave a very good hint, there is a playground application. NB: abaplint is a custom tool.

Comment: Thanks SandraRossi and RaTiO